# FragmentTransaction is not applicable for arguments(int, FragmentActivity)

Tags: android

Please am working on this app the frame work is good but i want to implement a menu as that of gmail that is slide navigation menu but all my activities are extended from fragmentactivity class instead of jst activity. So inside my mainactivity which is also extendin fragmentactivity

I have this.

```
if(fragment!=null){ 
    FragmentManager fmanager = getFragmanager();
    fmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}
```

But am getting an error msg that "the method replace(int,Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments(int, FragmentActivity)

Comment: I believe you may be confused. The logic you're using is to handle fragments (class Fragment) inside a normal activity. I don't know how FragmentActivity work (seems to be old fashion) but that is not the way

Comment: Yea i thought it would work that way but it seems am on a wrong path can please help me out

Comment: I can't explain fragments in one stackoverflow comment :). Start reading this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html and come with specific questions that may arise.